# Is there a hotkey for automatic key-frame insertion? If not how do I set it?

Tags: timeline

I am searching for a couple of days now but can't find a hot key for that button and I can't find how to set it.
So please help.

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a key as far as I know.

## 2.79

To add it in 2.7 you should go to User Preferences(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>), Input tab:

[image]

And add a new hotkey for the area of Blender you would want it to work in. You can use `wm.context_toggle` with a context attribute `tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto`:
[image]

## 2.8

In 2.8 you can just right click the icon and choose Assign Shortcut:

[image]

It seems the button does not refresh instantly on the interface when you use such a shortcut. It refreshes when you move the mouse to another editor or perform some other action that refreshes the UI. I believe that should not affect the functionality.

Comment: I work with 2.8. In the beginning I thought this is the solution and it probably is for a future version of blender. But I downloaded a new version and it went berserk. So I wait with this until it wil get more stable.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue. Cannot make it go beserk. Saved user preferences may have something to do with it. You could try to backup them and 'Load Factory Settings'.

Comment: I do not know what happened yesterday but to day it behaves correctly! Maybe I did not changed the location of the mouse pointer to another editor.